# `flip` function implementation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Anyone please share the implementation of `flip` function in JavaScript. What I need is to reverse the first and the second parameters of a function.

Let's assume I have:

```
const funcName = (arg1) => (arg2) => (arg3) => { ... }
```

I want it turns to:

```
const funcName = (arg2) => (arg1) => (arg3) => { ... }
```

And like this:

```
const funcName = (arg3) => (arg2) => (arg1) => { ... }
```

Comment: could you please explain more

Comment: You don't have first and second parameters to your function, you have an arrow function that returns another function and then another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flip` notoriously takes a function of two arguments `a` and `b`, and gives you back a different function with the arguments flipped.

if you want to keep the curried version, this is a way of implementing `flip`

```js
// f :: a -> b -> c
// flip f :: b -> a -> c

const flip = f => b => a => f(a)(b)
const f = a => b => ({ [a]: b });

console.log(
  f('name')('Alex'),       // { name: 'Alex' }
  flip(f)('Alex')('name'), // { name: 'Alex' }
)
```

Extending it to functions of more than two arguments is relatively simple, as `flip` can be composed quite easily.

Comment: Thank you so much, especially  for mentioning that it cab be composed easily!

Comment: How do you compose `flip`?

Answer (score 3):

A simple thing to do would be:

```js
const flip = (fn) => (arg1, arg2) => fn(arg2, arg1);

const reverse = (fn) => (...args) => fn(...args.reverse());

const log = reverse(console.log.bind(null));

log('Giuseppe', 'is', 'name', 'my');
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/flip.js

You could do something like this

```js
function flip(fn) {
   return function(a, b) {
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
       args[0] = b;
       args[1] = a;
       return fn.apply(this, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't really match up with the different arrow function arguments

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/TrustworthyGreenyellowSites Check it out in repl

Comment: but it's a function like `a => b => c => ...` and not `(a, b) =>...`